Spring create binders programmatically for Spring cloud stream Kafka binder
In our project we have multiple Spring boot micro services that consume the message using Kafka and send the message to another kafka topic and we have created a common spring library that uses Spring cloud stream kafka binder to consume and sending the messages to the another topic.
All the microservices are using this common library and passing inputTopic,outputTopic and errorTopic names. There is a requirement to create the binders dynamically based on spring.cloud.stream.function.definition.
Suppose we have 2 function.definitions then the library should create 2 binders dynamically instead of we update the config for the 2 binders.
Below is the approach that I am trying to follow. I am planning templatizing(application-template.yml) the spring cloud stream binder config like below.
application-template.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
#      function:
#        definition: ${binders.names}
      bindings:
        ${binding_name}-in-0:
          destination: ${${binding_name}.input-name:NONE}
          consumer:
            auto-startup: ${${binding_name}.auto-startup:true}
            max-attempts: ${${binding_name}.max-attempt:3}
            concurrency: ${${binding_name}.concurrency:30}
            batch-mode: ${${binding_name}.batch-mode:true}
        ${binding_name}-out-0:
          destination: ${${binding_name}.destination-name:NONE}
    kafka:
      binder:
        broker: ${broker.name:test}
      bindings:
        ${binding_name}-in-0:
          consumer:
            enableDLQ: ${${binding_name}.enableDLQ:true}
            dlqName: ${${binding_name}.dlqName:NONE}

application.yml file
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: ${binders.names}
binders:
    names: function1;function2
    
function1:
  input-name: input-topic-1
  destination-name: output-topic-1
  auto-startup: true
  max-attempt: 5
  concurrency: 10
  batch-mode: true
  enableDLQ: true
  dlqName: dlq-topic-1

function2:
  input-name: input-topic-2
  destination-name: output-topic-2
  auto-startup: true
  max-attempt: 5
  concurrency: 10
  batch-mode: true
  enableDLQ: true
  dlqName: dlq-topic-2    

Using Custom EnvironmentPostProcessor I am loading application-template.yml and replacing ${binding_name} with ${binders.names} and setting these properties into System environments.
package com.spring.cloud.stream.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

 private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "customBinderProperties";

 @Override
 public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
     Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application-template.yml");

     try {
         Map<String,Object> propMap = new HashMap<>();
         Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
         Map<String,Object> yamlProp = yaml.load(resource.getInputStream());
         flattenMap(yamlProp,propMap,null);
         Properties properties = System.getProperties();
         for(String propertyName: properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
             propMap.put(propertyName, properties.getProperty(propertyName));
         }
         
         String functionName = environment.getProperty("binders.names");
         if (functionName != null) {
             String[] binders = functionName.split(";");

             for (String binder : binders) {
                 environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("dynamicCOnfig", replacePlaceHolders(environment,binder,propMap)));
             }
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load application-template.yml", e);
     }
 }

 private Map<String, Object> replacePlaceHolders(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, String binder,
        Map<String, Object> propMap) {
    String placeholder ="${binding_name}";
    Map<String,Object> newProperties = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : propMap.entrySet()) {
        String propertyName = entry.getKey();
        String propertyValue = entry.getValue().toString();
        if(propertyName.contains(placeholder) || propertyValue.contains(placeholder)) {
            String newPropertyName = propertyName.replace(placeholder, binder);
            String newPropertyValue = propertyValue.replace(placeholder, binder);
            String changePropertyValue = environment.resolvePlaceholders(newPropertyValue);
            newProperties.put(newPropertyName, changePropertyValue);
        }else{
            newProperties.put(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("newProperties properties are "+newProperties);
    newProperties.forEach((key,value) -> System.setProperty(key, value.toString()));;
    return newProperties;
}

private void flattenMap(Map<String, Object> yamlProp, Map<String, Object> target, Object path) {
    for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry: yamlProp.entrySet()) {
        String key = (path == null ? entry.getKey(): path+"."+entry.getKey());
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if(value instanceof Map) {
            flattenMap((Map<String, Object>)value, target, key);
        }else {
            target.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    
}
}

Using Custom ApplicationContextAware class I am trying to create the binders.names beans    dynamically as well like below.
package com.spring.cloud.stream.test;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Component
public class CustomApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware{

    @Value("${binders.names}")
    private String customBinders;
    
    private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void configureFunctions(){
        String[] functionNames = customBinders.split(";");
        for(String functionName: functionNames) {
            applicationContext.registerBean(functionName,Consumer.class,() -> createConsumers(functionName));
        }
    }
    
    private Consumer<Message<?>> createConsumers(String functionName){
        return message -> {
            System.out.println("Custom messages are {} "+message);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext=(GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        
    }
}

Main Application
package com.spring.cloud.stream.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringKafkaDynamicBindersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaDynamicBindersApplication.class, args);
    }
}

spring.factories

org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
com.spring.cloud.stream.test.CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor

After running the application I could see properties are getting loaded into environment and Spring is trying to call function Bean
but throwing ClassCastException saying ArrayList cant be convert into org.springframework.messaging.Message.
With above approach if I want to add one more binders then only change I'll have to do is add new functionDefinition in properties.
First of all is my above approach correct to creat the binders programatically? If yes what is a reason of getting the ClassCastException. Find below the stacktrace of the error. Appreciate any help.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList
cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.Message
(java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
org.springframework.messageing.Message is in unnamed module of loader
'app') at
org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:1008)
at
org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:743)
at
org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:589)
at
org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:84)
at
org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:791)
at
org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:623)
at
org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)


It is hard to see where the problem is - it sounds like you have a non-trivial setup. Can you provide more stacktrace? I suggest creating a small sample application and providing it on GH or a zip file. Then we can see what's going on. Btw - spring.cloud.stream.function.definition is deprecated and removed from the newer versions. The correct property name is spring.cloud.function.definition.

Thanks sobychacko. I'll try to create a sample application till then I have updated the question with the last stack trace of the error see if that will help to find the issue.

Hi Sobychacko, It seems I cant add the zip so shared the code in the question only.
